# Nhibernate - QueryOver JoinAlias Which has no relational Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-criteria

I have to join two tables, but there is no for those fields. Is it possible to do it?

For example

`TableA (ID, MachineID, EquipmentID)`

`Machine (MachineID, Description)`

There is a mapping for `TableA.MachineID => Machine.MachineID`. I can use Join for that and no issues with it.

Now I need to join `TableA.EquipmentID => Machine.MachineID`. Is It possible to do this without mapping fields?

Comment: do you have `class TabkleAEntity { public Machine Machine { get; set;} public Machine Equipment { get; set;} }`?

Comment: You can only do this using a subquery. It is described in [this blog post](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I saw that link before too. Every ware I saw has shown very simple samples. It is difficult to find complex one.

Comment: I have class TableA{ public Machine{get;set} .... }